# Out of range exception while convert datetime2 to datetime data type

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-express

I've got an exception while updating a `datetime` column on SQL Server 2008 Express:

```
eventinfo.StartDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(start, 
                                              "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", 
                                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
db.Entry(eventinfo).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Exception:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.The statement has been terminated.

Any idea how to avoid this exception?

Comment: What was the value you were converting?

Comment: Showing how `start` is defined and populated might be a good start (no pun intended).

Comment: one of the datetime looks like this: 03/08/2012 12:39:00 PM

Comment: @Aaron, your suggestion was useful. I should match date format as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain of Sql Server's date/time data types is as follows:

- `datetime2` (100-nanosecond precision)
  1753-01-01T00:00:00.0 — 9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999.
- `datetime` (millisecond precision...sort of)
  1753-01-01T00:00:00.000 — 9999-12-31T23:59:59.997
- `smalldatetime` (1-second precision)
  1900-01-01T00:00:00 — 2079-06-06T23:59:59

The CLR `DateTime` struct has 100-nanosecond precision as well. It is a count of 100-second ticks since its epoch (0001-01-01T00:00:00). Its domain is 0001-01-01T00:00:00 — 9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999.

You will notice the extended domain of the CLR `DateTime` as compared to SQL Server's `datetime2`.

The default value of the CLR's `DateTime` is its epoch (0001-01-01T00:00:00). Any value prior to 1753-01-01T00:00:00 will throw an out of range exception.

In all likelyhood, your `DateTime` value is somehow not getting initialized or DateTime.ParseExact() is getting handed junk data, parsing it successfuly and winding up with a date/time prior to 1753-01-01.

Comment: Good to know but I don't think this is the case.

Comment: Sorry about the previous comment. Yes, you're right. one of my date value out of the form was null. i.e., 0001-01-01 something. that caused this issue. Thanks a lot. I accepted your answer!